# A good book on convolutional neural networks

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, neural-networks

Good evening! Do you know any good books about convolutional neural networks?

In particular, I would like to know:

1) How are the backpropagations for convolutional and pooling layers are calculated?

2) Are the dropout layers involved in backpropagation calculations?

Comment: THis is a very good starting point for CNN. http://cs231n.github.io/

Comment: Backpropagation works the same way for any neural network of the form $$x_{n+1} = f(M_n x_n), \qquad E = \|x_N-y\|^2$$ Replacing $M_n x_n$ by $x_n \ast h_n$ yield a convolutional layer